# How to fix errors in this function

Tags: r

Write a function named *countConsecutivePairs* that accepts a numeric vector as an argument and counts the pairs of consecutive elements whose difference is less than 2.

You should stop the execution and print an appropriate error message if the argument is not numeric.

Here is my code

```
countConsecutivepairs=function(z){
  if(!(is.vector(z)))
     stop("Error"
  if(class(z)!="numeric")
     stop("Error")
  
  for(i in z) {
  if(abs(z[i]-z[i+1])!=2){
    next
   }
   print(c(z[i],z[i+1]) 
 }
}
```

I get a bunch of errors when I do this. And Im not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You miss several `)` in your code.

And thanks to @Jan, as @Ace123 use `z[i]`'s in code and also want to check **consecutive elements**, we should call those elements by `i` against length of `z`.

```
countConsecutivepairs<- function(z){
  if(!(is.vector(z))){
    stop("Error")
  }

  if(class(z)!="numeric"){
    stop("Error")
  }
  for(i in 1:(length(z)-1)) {
    if(abs(z[i]-z[i+1])!=2){
      next
    }
    
    
    print(c(z[i],z[i+1]))
          
          
  }
    
}
countConsecutivepairs(c(1,2,3,5,7))
[1] 3 5
[1] 5 7
```

Comment: @Park: you also fixed the indexing error. The PO used `i` in `for(i in z)` as index. YOu corrected this. Please explain.